# Animation of a canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i want to move the entire canvas i created(turtle graphics inside) like a bouncing ball on the screen. Here is the code am using to achieve it.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

def draw_c(turtle,width,shade):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(((width/2)-(width/5)),-((width/4)))
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.shape("blank")
    
    turtle.pensize(width/5)
    turtle.pencolor(shade,shade,shade)
    
    turtle.left(50)
    turtle.circle((width/2-width/10),-280)
    turtle.penup()
    return turtle.turtlesize()


def move_canvas(canvas_name,speedx,speedy):
    global start_position_x,start_position_y
    start_position_x += speedx
    start_position_y += speedy
    print("move x to:",start_position_x)
    print("move y to:",start_position_y)
    canvas_name.place(x=start_position_x,y=start_position_y)
    print("actual x coord is",canvas_name.winfo_x())
    print("acutal y coord is",canvas_name.winfo_y())
    my_window.after(0, move_canvas(canvas_name,speedx,speedy))

my_window = tk.Tk()
width_value = my_window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = my_window.winfo_screenheight()
start_position_x = width_value/2
start_position_y = height_value/2
my_window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width_value,height_value))
my_window.configure(bg = 'white')

speedx = 9
speedy = 9




width = 40*0.00145*100
width_pixel  = (width*96)/2.54

canvas = tk.Canvas(my_window,height=width_pixel,width=width_pixel,bg='white')
canvas.place(x=start_position_x,y=start_position_y)

turtle_name = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
turtle_name.speed('fastest')



draw_c(turtle_name,width_pixel,0)

move_canvas(canvas,speedx,speedy)

my_window.mainloop()
```

It is not behaving like it should, while the global variable i created(start_position_x) is updating every cycle, the place command inside the function is not updating the co-ordinates. here is the output of the print statements.

```
move x to:9334.0
move y to:9206.0
actual x coord is:640
actual y coord is:512
move x to:9343.0
move y to:9215.0
actual x coord is:640
actual y coord is:512
```

The place function is not updating as expected, what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to modify the `move_canvas` function a bit.

```
def move_canvas(canvas_name, speedx, speedy):
    global start_position_x, start_position_y
    my_window.update()
    start_position_x += speedx
    start_position_y += speedy
    print("move x to:", start_position_x)
    print("move y to:", start_position_y)
    canvas_name.place(x=start_position_x, y=start_position_y)
    print("actual x coord is", canvas_name.winfo_x())
    print("acutal y coord is", canvas_name.winfo_y())
    my_window.after(0, lambda : move_canvas(canvas_name, speedx, speedy))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Calling `my_window.update()` at the beginning of the function does not solve the issue.  It should be called after `canvas_name.place(...)` instead.

Comment: Perfect, it works now! thank you so much kimhyunju and 
acw1668